# JQuery/PHP multiple files one at a time with only one input field

Tags: php, jquery

I search through the net but didn't find much things on my problem. Hope someone here can help!
As i write in the title I want to upload mutliple files, one at a time, with only one input.
I tried to do this using JQuery as you can see below, but obviously it doesn't work!
Anyone can help, please?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '.file',function(){
            $('<input type="file" name="file[]" class="file" size="60" />').appendTo($("#divAjout"));
            $("div input:first-child").remove();    
          return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <title>test input file unique pour plusieurs fichiers</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div id="divAjout">
        <input type="file" name="file[]" class="file" id='file' size="60" />
        </div>


        <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo'<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);echo'<pre>';} ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: first search in google gave me this :http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload

Comment: Why are you removing the first input when you add a new one? The file hasn't been uploaded yet.

Comment: Heres another that is done with JQuery http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @FaceOfJock: thank you for your quick response but I know this link and it doesn't do what I want: I want to upload files one at a time, not selectioning mutliple files at a time as this tut. shows.

Comment: @Barmar: I know that the upload is not done when I remove the input, that's the point, how can I remove/hide the input but $_FILE still contains the files to upload

Comment: @Christopher: I know this plugin but it's not the point for my question! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Maybe hide the old input instead of removing it?

Comment: @Acidy the state of your current code it won't even upload a file, you are just removing the input field. I would highly recommend that you use a pre-built library and modify it to your needs instead of writing this from scratch.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. You say you want to upload one file at a time, but you're using an array so it seems like you want to upload them all at once.

Comment: @Barnar: I already try with hide but it only works one time, I don't figure out why for the moment.  name=file[] can be use for several input on a page, not only for uploading multiple file all at once.

Comment: Ok, I've found a  plugin doing what i want: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ I'll try to figure out how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can clone input file with incrementing name attribute, like file[0], file[1], file[2], etc.

```
function readURL(input) {
                var index = ($(input).data('index'));
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $(input).parent().children('.newImage')
                            .attr('src', e.target.result)
                            .height(120);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

                    $('.addPh').show();
                    $('.addPh').last().clone().insertBefore($('#addPhoto')).hide();
                    ++index;
                    $('.addPh').last().children('.photo_new').data('index', index).attr('name', 'photo_new['+index+']');
                }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addPhoto').click(function () {
        $('.photo_new').last().click();
    });

});
```

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/w0cd3Ls4/3/